# How to write in Mongolian language? (couldn't find it in set-input-method)

Tags: input-method

I sometimes write in my native language (Mongolian).
There seems no entry for it in `set-input-method`.

Should add it from other place / or install some packages?

Comment: [On Ubuntu] Following advice here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43976/list-all-valid-kbd-layouts-variants-and-toggle-options-to-use-with-setxkbmap I ran `sed '/! variant/,/^$/!d;/Mongolian/!d' < /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`. It gave me mon_trad        cn: Mongolian (Bichig)
  mon_trad_todo   cn: Mongolian (Todo)
  mon_trad_xibe   cn: Mongolian (Xibe)
  mon_trad_manchu cn: Mongolian (Manchu)
  mon_trad_galik  cn: Mongolian (Galik)
  mon_todo_galik  cn: Mongolian (Todo Galik)
  mon_manchu_galik cn: Mongolian (Manchu Galik)`

All these should be available in `setxkbmap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update: this has been added to `Emacs-29.1` [here:](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=5fecdbcd81db3d4a06277400c458d8ca7dcf7462)

---

Following [this answer to similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60520/how-to-add-a-new-input-method-for-syriac-script-in-emacs),
I made following lines, and added to `init.el`.

```
(quail-define-package
    "Mongolian-trans" "Mg-trans" "S>" t
    "Input method for Mongolian transcription."
    nil t nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil t)

(quail-define-rules
    ;; keys (without shift)
    ("q" ?ф) ("w" ?ц) ("e" ?у) ("r" ?ж) ("t" ?э) ("y" ?н) ("u" ?г)
    ("i" ?ш) ("o" ?ү) ("p" ?з) ("[" ?к) ("]" ?ъ) ("a" ?й) ("s" ?ы)
    ("d" ?б) ("f" ?ө) ("g" ?а) ("h" ?х) ("j" ?р) ("k" ?о) ("l" ?л)
    (";" ?д) ("'" ?п) ("z" ?я) ("x" ?ч) ("c" ?ё) ("v" ?с) ("b" ?м)
    ("n" ?и) ("m" ?т) ("," ?ь) ("." ?в) ("/" ?ю)

    ;; keys (with shift)
    ("Q" ?ф) ("W" ?Ц)  ("E" ?У) ("R" ?Ж) ("T" ?Э) ("Y" ?Н) ("U" ?Г)
    ("I" ?Ш) ("O" ?Ү)  ("P" ?З) ("{" ?К) ("}" ?Ъ) ("A" ?Й) ("S" ?Ы)
    ("D" ?Б) ("F" ?Ө)  ("G" ?А) ("H" ?Х) ("J" ?Р) ("K" ?О) ("L" ?Л)
    (":" ?Д) ("\"" ?П) ("Z" ?Я) ("X" ?Ч) ("C" ?Ё) ("V" ?С) ("B" ?М)
    ("N" ?И) ("M" ?Т)  ("<" ?Ь) (">" ?В) ("?" ?Ю)


    ;; numbers keys (without shift)
    ("1" ?№) ("2" ?-) ("3" ?\") ("4" ?₮) ("5" ?:) ("6" ?.)
    ("7" ?_) ("8" ?,) ("9" ?%)  ("0" ??) ("-" ?е) ("=" ?щ)


    ;; numbers keys (with shift)
    ("!" ?1) ("@" ?2) ("#" ?3) ("$" ?4) ("%" ?5) ("^" ?6)
    ("&" ?7) ("*" ?8) ("(" ?9) (")" ?0) ("_" ?Е) ("+" ?Щ)
)
```

Comment: Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` with your improvements, so that Emacs will support the Mongolian input method by default in future.

Answer (score 2):

Does `Mongolian` look like `Russian` / `Cyrillic`?

---

1. `M-x view-hello-file`. (`Options → Multilingual Environment → Show Multilingual Sample Text`)
2. Search for `Mongolian` in that file.  You will see an entry like this.

```
Mongolian (монгол хэл)  Сайн байна уу?
```

3. Place the cursor on the mongolian chars, and do `C-u M-x describe-char`

You will see an entry like the one below.  Note that it reports `script` as `cyrillic`.

```
             position: 2799 of 4623 (61%), column: 18
            character: х (displayed as х) (codepoint 1093, #o2105, #x445)
              charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x0445
               script: cyrillic
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Strong L2R, Y:2-byte Cyrillic, c:Chinese, h:Korean, j:Japanese, y:Cyrillic
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 445" or "C-x 8 RET CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER HA"
          buffer code: #xD1 #x85
            file code: #xD1 #x85 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code):
    ftcrhb:-GOOG-Noto Sans CJK KR-regular-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x168)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER HA
  old-name: CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER KHA
  general-category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
  decomposition: (1093) ('х')

[back]
```

4. So you need to setup a cyrillic input method.
5. So, do `M-x set-input-method RET` (`Options → Multilingual Environment → Select Input Method...`) and pick one of the following input methods

```
cyrillic-tuvan
cyrillic-jcuken
cyrillic-serbian
cyrillic-yawerty
cyrillic-translit
cyrillic-ukrainian
cyrillic-macedonian
cyrillic-jis-russian
```

6. Once in `cyrillic` input, do `M-x describe-input-method` (`Help → Describe → Describe Input Method...` and `Options → Multilingual Environment → Describe Input Method...`)
7. You switch back to normal input method with `M-x toggle-input-method RET` (`Options → Multilingual Environment → Toggle Input Method`)

---

You can also do `Options → Multilingual Environment → Set Language Environment → Cyrillic`  and set up a specific `cyrillic` language environment.

You can also do `M-x customize-variable RET default-input-method RET` , and set it to your preferred input method.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply,
Yes, Mongolian use Cyrillic-alphabet. But (Main reason not using other cyrrilic inputs):
The keyboard layout was completely different than other Cyrillic inputs.

Comment: [image of Mongolian layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Mongolian_keyboard_win.png),
.
[image of Russian layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/KB_Russian.svg/1280px-KB_Russian.svg.png)

Comment: You can ditch emacs altogether, and use whatever method your desktop provides.  On `GNOME`, you can use `ibus` method  `mongolian`, and it seems to have same mapping as what you have posted.

Comment: Mongolian also has two extra letters that are not in Russian and other Cyrillic alphabets, namely ө, ү.